# FindByEmail is missing in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

**How to enable method 'FindByEmail'?** in ASP.net

I have the following code in asp.net

**File RoleActions.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
...
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

...
            IdentityResult IdRoleResult;
            IdentityResult IdUserResult;

            //Create a Role object by using the ApplicationDbContext object.
            // The RoleStore is only allowed to contain IdentityRole objects.
            var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);

            //Create a RoleManager object that is only allowed to contain IdentityRole objects.
            //When creating the RoleManager object, you pass in (as a parameter) a new RoleStore object.
            var roleMgr = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

            //Then, you create the "canEdit" role if it doesn't already exist.
            if (!roleMgr.RoleExists("canEdit"))
            {
                IdRoleResult = roleMgr.Create(new IdentityRole { Name = "canEdit" });
            }

            // Create a UserManager object based on the UserStore object and the ApplicationDbContext object. Note that you can create new objects and use the as parameters in a single line of code, rather than using multiple lines of code, as you did for the RoleManager object.

            var userMgr = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
            var appUser = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = "canEditUser@example.com",
                Email = "canEditUser@example.com"
            };
            IdUserResult = userMgr.Create(appUser, "password1");

            // If the new "canEdit" user was successfully created, add the "canEdit" user to the "canEdit" role.
            if (!userMgr.IsInRole(userMgr.FindByEmail("canEditUser@example.com").Id, "canEdit"))
            {
                IdUserResult = userMgr.AddToRole(userMgr.FindByEmail("canEditUser@example.com").Id, "canEdit");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**File IdentityModels.cs**

```
// You can add User data for the user by adding more properties to your User class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{       
}
```

I get the error on build :

> " Error   1   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<....ApplicationUser>'
>   does not contain a definition for 'FindByEmail' and no extension
>   method 'FindByEmail' accepting a first argument of type
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<....ApplicationUser>' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FindByEmail was added in **ASP.NET Identity 2.0** (see anouncement https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/12/20/announcing-preview-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity-2-0-0-alpha1/).

To have FindByEmail install latest packages

- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.OWIN